# What kind of knife is this?

Tags: knives

Found this knife in my Grandmother's collection. None of us can figure out what the semi-circle shape and slots are for (see attached picture).  Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How sharply cut are the slots? I have seen multi-purpose tools with slots like that to be used as peelers/graters. The bottle opener at the hilt would also suggest a strange multi-tool.

Comment: @sobachatina, the slits aren't sharp at all, they're quite smooth. I guess multi tool makes sense, but I have no idea what the rest could be used for.

Comment: Is the spine sharp, making it usable as a mezzaluna?

Comment: @rackandboneman No, the spine isn't sharp. Good question though.

Comment: If the metal is tempered right to support a serrated edge well, it will probably support sharpening the spine ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a multi-tool, which appear to have been given out as novelties. The bottle opener and serrated knife are obvious, the slits are there to act as a pot strainer, the semi-circle shape and flat surface allows you to hold it against the edge of a pot and pour out the liquid while keeping solid bits in. I found a few of them on Ebay, the good links (as of this answer) are:

[Vintage Farmers Co-op Creamery 1967 Bread Knife](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/FT3-Vintage-Farmers-Co-op-Creamery-1967-Bread-knife-gratuity-gift-Deer-Creek-MN-/332061924269?hash=item4d506edbad:g:XpkAAOSwcUBYUIzm)

[Vintage Multi-Purpose Knife Bottle Opener Strainer Stainless Wood Handle Japan](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Multi-Purpose-Knife-Bottle-Opener-Strainer-Stainless-Wood-Handle-Japan-/122032580059) - 
*Given the nature of Ebay I can't guarantee these links will be good for long*

According to the inscriptions on some they were given out by a couple of different Farmer's Co-ops and a Drilling company...does yours have any writing on it?

[image]

...and here is a picture of a pot drainer (single purpose) as it would be used.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, a pot strainer. That makes sense. We tried a Google image search, but that failed. Guess our Google-fu wasn't as strong as yours!  It does have writing on the side, it says "Keller Grain and Feed."

Comment: As a 'novelty' item, I would not expect it to work particularly well. On the other hand it looks like you could get $14.95 off of Ebay for it if you want.

Comment: Looks handy for camping though.